# Error in the browser console TypeError: $(...).aaDropdownMenu is not a function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to make an error in the browser console, it does not cause interference in the site, but it should not really be, help me to remove it.

I'm getting this error in the browser console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).aaDropdownMenu is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.onDOMReady (dropdown-menu.self-5794b6ca26364ce522cb47a8ef050870fda0b886cfeef69ec27ef116900f1984.js?body=1:121)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery3.self-5af507e253c37e9c9dcf65064fc3f93795e6e28012780579975a4d709f4074ad.js?body=1:5184)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery3.self-5af507e253c37e9c9dcf65064fc3f93795e6e28012780579975a4d709f4074ad.js?body=1:4992)
    at Object.e.dispatch (turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6)
    at r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad (turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:7)
    at r.pageLoaded (turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:7)
    at turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6
```

My Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'devise'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.7'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'dotenv-rails'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.2'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.3'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.3'

gem 'bootsnap', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.1'
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '~> 4.7', '>= 4.7.0.2'
gem "jquery-slick-rails"

gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.10', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.4', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.3'
  gem 'capistrano-passenger', '>= 0.1.1'
  gem 'capistrano3-puma'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

A section of code that is cursed in the console

```
$.widget.bridge('aaDropdownMenu', ActiveAdmin.DropdownMenu);

onDOMReady = function() {
  return $('.dropdown_menu').aaDropdownMenu();    <<<<errors
};
```

Comment: I was helped to delete the file jquery-1.11.0.min.js